# Parse Swift - Sign Up User, Log Them In, Add Them to Role

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When I use the following code I am trying to sign up a user, log them in and then add them to a role. Please can anyone help with why the PFUser.CurrentUser() seems to return a nil value every time and therefore won't let me add to a role?

```
@IBAction func trySignUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (txtStoreNumber.text != "" && txtEmail.text != "" && txtUsername.text != "" && txtPassword.text != "" && selectWorkLevel.selectedSegmentIndex != -1){
        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = txtUsername.text
        user.password = txtPassword.text
        user.email = txtEmail.text

        // Other non-standard fields...
        user["Store"] = txtStoreNumber.text
        user["Forename"] = txtForename.text
        user["Surname"] = txtSurname.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                self.showSucccess("Success: User Created")

                // Login the user
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.txtUsername.text, password: self.txtPassword.text) {
                    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if user != nil {
                        // Put the user in to a role
                        var roleName = ""

                        switch self.selectWorkLevel.selectedSegmentIndex{
                        case 0:
                            roleName = "StoreManager"
                        case 1:
                            roleName = "DeputyManager"
                        case 2:
                            roleName = "TeamLeader"
                        default:
                            roleName = "Other"
                        }

                        var queryRole = PFRole.query()
                        queryRole!.whereKey("name", equalTo: roleName)
                        queryRole!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (roleObject, error) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                var roleToAddUser = roleObject as! PFRole
                                roleToAddUser.users.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
                                roleToAddUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                                    if (error == nil){
                                        self.showSucccess("Success: User Created")
                                    }else{
                                        // Provide Validation and Error Message
                                        self.showError("Error \(error!.code): " + error!.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                })

                            }else{
                                // Provide Validation and Error Message
                                self.showError("Error \(error!.code): " + error!.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        // Provide Validation and Error Message
                        self.showError("Error \(error!.code): " + error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }

            }else{
                // Provide Validation and Error Message
                self.showError("Error \(error!.code): " + error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }else{
        if (selectWorkLevel.selectedSegmentIndex != -1){
            self.showError("Error: Fields Incomplete")
        }else{
            self.showError("Error: Select a Work Level")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but after signing up a user, you should not have to log them in. They should be logged in already.

Comment: That's what I thought but the PFUser.CurrentUser() was nil

Comment: Then there must be an issue with signing up the user...verify that your signup code matches this: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-signing-up Your block does not look correct to me in terms of extra parenthesis as well as variable types for the bool and NSError...